# angular: injector with promise-ajax and $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-modal

I have a shared ajax method returning promise. I'm trying to use $uibModal popup with it. Ajax call works fine, but the popup doesn't close when I'm done with ajax. For the ajax call, it doesn't matter to me if it is synchronous or not in this case, I just want to close the popup once I got the value from ajax call.  I'm guessing the popup is invisible to promise, but maybe it is something else. I'm kind of new to angular, maybe there is a trick for angular here. I'd like to fix this. Much appreciate your time.
My shared ajax method is this:

```
app.value('getImgSrc', function(location, prefix, async){                
    var postData = {location:location, prefix:prefix};
    var src = "";
    var promiss = $.ajax({
        async: async,
        url:'/imgTool/getImgSrc',    
        dataType:"json",
        data: postData
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(data.src){  
           src = data.src;
        }else{
            $log.info("getImgSrc for prefix:",prefix,"data:", data);
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR){
        $log.error("getImgSrc ERROR, jqXHR:", jqXHR);
    });
    return promiss;
});
```

And here is the controller utilizing the above method:

```
app.controller('PreviewCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location, $injector,$uibModal) {
    ....
    var location = .....
    var prefix = "/"+$scope.crop.name+"/"+$rootScope.jsonCrops.file;
    $scope.src = "";        

    var popup = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'progress.html', 
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        size: "sm"
    });

    var getImgSrc = $injector.get('getImgSrc'); 
    var callback = getS3ImgSrc(location,prefix, false).done(function(){});
    if(callback.responseJSON.src){
        this.popup.dismiss('cancel');
        $scope.src = callback.responseJSON.src;
    }

});
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Angular with jQuery's `$.ajax` method?

Comment: @Phil: I'm not using $http because the returned json response was missing some of the values for some reason - a  url value, and since ajax does the right thing, I thought I could use it instead.

Comment: I fixed my script to use $http angular http, and I see now a little better what is going on with the popup, it works as expected after all